# Strange merging - list of words

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists of words like this:

```
texts=[['word1', 'word2', 'word3']['word4', 'word5', 'word6']]
```

My desired output would be:

```
texts=[['word1 word2 word3']['word4 word5 word6']
```

This is what I tried:

for item in texts:

```
item=[" ".join([word for word in item])]
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

Comment: You have a list of lists not a flat list,`[[" ".join(sub)] for sub in item]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just pass the sub lists to `join`:

```
In [62]: [[' '.join(sub_list)] for sub_list in texts]
Out[62]: [['word1 word2 word3'], ['word4 word5 word6']]
```

Comment: Thanks, it was very simple but I couldn't realize.